# When does Skullcage have its effect activated?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am new to Magic, so forgive me if this is common knowledge.

Does the opponent's draw step happen before or after the [Skullcage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Skullcage) condition is checked?

Comment: If you're new, I would suggest reading the [Basic Rulebook](http://media.wizards.com/2014/docs/EN_M15_QckStrtBklt_LR_Crop.pdf). It covers a lot of the basics of playing Magic, though I can't find anything in it that covers this specific question.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Will do once I get the chance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skullcage triggers during your opponent's upkeep step, which is before their draw step. The order of steps in a Magic turn is

1. Untap
2. **Upkeep**
3. **Draw**
4. Precombat Main
5. Combat
6. Postcombat Main
7. End